# Cocoapods podfile pod name

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I am very new to cocoapods and iOS development, and I'm trying to set up my first pod file. 
I'm having a hard time finding the right name for the pod, for example,

```
pod 'GooglePlus'
```

I added "GooglePlus" in the podfile, since GooglePlus.framework was the name I see in the xcode panel on the left, however I got

```
Unable to find a specification for 'GooglePlus'
```

error, after Pod install.

After a long google search I found out that the proper name for the GooglePlus is 'google-plus-ios-sdk'. However, I have more than 30 dependencies to name, and I can't seem to find any clue on other dependency names. Can someone please give me a piece of advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for all pods in the master repository on http://cocoapods.org

Comment: Tom's answer is correct but I also wanted to add that many of the frameworks that I use are in github and they will have a file called a *.podspec. If you open that file you can see the pod name that you would use in your podfile. That sometimes helps me. If I need a specific version then I will go to cocoapods.org to see which versions are available.